# Error Inserting value 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=2;' into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, varchar

The Error: String or binary data would be truncated.

I did not find  a reason for this error. the column is a varchar(50) and when I try with 'FREQ=DAILY;' it works just fine

```
INSERT INTO TASKS (RECURRENCERULE)
VALUES('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=2;');
```

anybody knows what it could be?

Comment: Well the data you are trying to insert looks to be 35 characters.  Is there any chance that your actual table definitions is less wide than 50 characters?

Comment: Have you added or altered tables recently? You may need to refresh the Object Explorer view in SSMS so as to see the current metadata on tables.

Comment: Checked and it's 50 characters. And did refresh the object explorer, still not working

Comment: Solved by droping the table and recreating it. Thanks